# Se4t Escaping for Zend_Form element description to false

Tags: zend-form, decorator, escaping

I'm having some trouble dealing with this.
This is inside my Zend_Form:

`$about = $this->addElement('textarea', 'about', array(
            'label'      => 'About:',
            'description' => 'some <strong>description</strong>',
            'required'   => false,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 1024)),
                )
        ));`

So for this about element I should have a description 'some **description**'.

The problem is the description is being escaped so what I get is 'some **description**...

Now If I try to use `$about->setDescription("some-text");` instead of setting the description key my description doesn't show. If I try to do anything that is described here ( http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450#comments-3486 ) either my form disappears or if I try to get the decorator I get null, so I get an error if I try to call the `$decorator->setOption()` method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know why this happens, maybe it is even intended to (maybe I failed reading all the documentation of Zend_Form).

Anyway, in the view script where I retrieve the form I can make it work...

How?
`<?php $this->form->getElement("about")->getDecorator("description")->setEscape(false); ?>`